# What's wrong with my date?

Tags: javascript, sql

I have the following javascript:

```
today = new Date(); //real "today" value if not using sample database

var curr_date = today.getDate();
var curr_month = today.getMonth();
curr_month++;
var curr_year = today.getFullYear().substr(2,2);
var t = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
this.queryText = this.queryText + " where exdate between '" + t + "' and '" + t + "'";
```

When I do this the query returns everything, but really, there is only 1 record between today and today.

If I manually write "between '8/9/12' and '8/9/12'" then the query is fine. What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: She's just not into you! Oh, not *that* kind of `date`...

Comment: How about if you manually write `between '9/9/12' and '9/9/12'`? You *are* incrementing the month...

Comment: '9/9/12' returns every record.

Comment: Well then I think there's your answer?

Comment: if your 'dates' are strings, then you are asking to be rejected.

Comment: as xdazz says just use `var curr_year = today.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`today.getFullYear()` returns a number, and a number doesn't have the method `.substr()`.

Comment: +1 Also very true. I wonder if it even got to the querytext line.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `curr_month`! So you are not checking "between today and today", but "between a month from today and a month from today", so I contend it is behaving correctly.

Side note: This will blow up on 1/29-1/31, 3/31, 5/31, etc. It is probably best to add 1 month to the date first, then extract the day/month/year.